Getting error message as NameError: name 'over' is not defined . Even after doing all necessary imports
emp_data_df.withColumn("Row_Number",row_number(),over(window))\
.withColumn("Rank",rank(),over(window))\
.withColumn("Dense_Rank",dense_rank(),over(window))\
.filter(col("Desnse_Rank")<=2)\
.show(truncate=False)

i am getting error message as NameError: name 'over' is not defined . How to resolve this?

Looks like you have a typo in your code. Instead of ',over()', it should be '.over()'
 emp_data_df.withColumn("Row_Number",row_number().over(window))\
.withColumn("Rank",rank().over(window))\
.withColumn("Dense_Rank",dense_rank().over(window))\
.filter(col("Desnse_Rank")<=2)\
.show(truncate=False)

